# Forces on different surfaces of a body immersed in water

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics

[image]

In the above condition it has been asked what is the force applied on the upper part of the sphere.
The solution says that the force on the upper half of the sphere is P<sub>0</sub>πr<sup>2</sup> + (1/3)πR<sup>3</sup>ρg.
But however I don't have a clue how is the term (1/3)πR<sup>3</sup>ρg coming into play. I know the force exerted on the upper part of the sphere should be directed downwards but I'm a bit confused on the magnitude.

Comment: Does it say net force or full force?

Comment: @JellyStrawberry the net force on the upper half of the sphere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The force down on the sphere is caused by the weight of the liquid and the weight of the atmosphere above the sphere. (The horizontal components of force on the curved segments of surface cancel out.)  The density of the sphere is not relevant, and it can be replaced by the the liquid displaced.  Then the force up on the upper half equals the force down plus the weight of the liquid which replaces it.
       (Po + ρgR)πR^2  =  F + ρg(2/3)πR^3
Solve for F

Comment: Well I'm confused on the term on the LHS, where you use the term ρgR*πR^2. How does that originate?

Comment: That's the force from the fluid pressure on the bottom of the upper hemisphere.

Comment: but how can fluid apply force at the bottom of the upper hemisphere as it is not in contact with the fluid- it is covered up by the lower half of the sphere.

Comment: Recall, that to simplify the calculations, I chose to replace the sphere with liquid, any part of which must still be in equilibrium.